# How to return the new value of a public String from a private void JButton?

Tags: java, swing

I have a public String in one class and is to be used by other classes. The value of this String can only be acquired with the use of a `JButton`. My code seems right but still I only get `null` returned from the button.

Below is my class containing the public String variable and the code for the `JButton`:

```
public class Seminar_Menu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    // Public String mentioned in quesiton
    public String Seminar_Choosen;
    ......

    //Button Code
    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Conduct_Seminar consem = new Conduct_Seminar();
        Seminar_Menu semen = new Seminar_Menu();

        String message = "Conduct this seminar?";
        String title = "Conduct";
        int reply = 
           JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, title, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {

            Seminar_Choosen = Title_Field.getText();

            consem.setVisible(true);
            semen.setVisible(false);
        }    
    }

   ......

}
```

I'm using `JFrame` Form by the way in Netbeans. Is there any other way of returning the value of `Seminar_Choosen`?

Comment: where is `Seminar_Choosen` defined in your button code? It looks like you should be calling `semen.Seminar_Choosen = Title_Field.getText()` that way you are actually setting the value of `Seminar_Choosen` in the `Seminar_Menu` object.

Comment: Also where is Title_Field defined?

Comment: `Seminar_Chosen` is a public String therefore I can use it in private void methods such as "Drag-and-drop" `JButtons`.

Comment: Title_Field is a Text field which I created in my `JFrame`.

Comment: You can use `Seminar_Choosen` in a private (or public, default, protected) method in the same class as the class the value is defined in or in a subclass of that class. Is the `jButton3ActionPerformed` a method in the Seminar_Menu class (or a subclass of Seminar_Menu)?

Comment: `semen.Seminar_Choosen = Title_Field.getText()` did't work.

Comment: Yes sir its a method in Seminar_Menu.

Comment: I'm female, no need (or desire) for sir. semen.Seminar_Choosen won't work if it is a method of that class. I thought your first method was in a different class than Seminar_Menu.

Comment: My apologies. I also tried this method: `semen.Seminar_Choosen = Title_Field.getText()` in different classes but still Seminar_Chosen gave me a null value.

Comment: hehehe..... semen...

Comment: Can you please add where Title_Field is defined?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Example {
  public static class myAction extends AbstractAction {
    String val;
    public myAction(String val) {
      this.val = val;
    }
    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      System.out.println("value: " + val);
    }
}
```

Then

```
JButton = new JButton(new Example(myString));
```

Comment: By convention, class names are capitalized; consider `private static class MyAction`.

Comment: +1  but for  `public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {` too